# Why is using module keyword instead of name when excluding dependencies in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependencies

For adding new dependencies we can use string and map notations:

```
 configurationName "group:name:version:classifier" configurationName
 group: group:, name: name, version: version, classifier: classifier
```

To exclude dependency we use:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.gradle.test.excludes:api:1.0") {
        exclude module: 'shared'
    }
}
```

So why we use the keyword **module**, not **name**. Is this something that comes from ANT or the reason is other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the original author considered `name` a bit too vague here, so he chose `module` instead. (It really is the name of the module.)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, module is more meaningful, but it is not consistent with the notations. If person don't know that, she will write exclude name:'shared' and will have headaches until remember this.

Comment: Sure, but it's too late to change it now, and I'm not sure it warrants an alternative notation.